# Jquery not working in IE Unable to get property 'top' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I am using Jquery-1.7 following is my jquery code.
It works in chrome but fails in IE

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function () {
    if ($(this).attr('scrollY') > $('#footerCenter').offset().top - $(window).height() - 60) {
        if ($('#earthMoonLink').hasClass('more')) {
            $('#earthMoonLink').removeClass('more').text('earth').attr({href: '#Earth', title: 'Back to Top'});
        }

    } else {
        if (!$('#earthMoonLink').hasClass('more')) {
            $('#earthMoonLink').addClass('more').text('moon').attr({href: '#Moon', title: 'Jump to Footer'});
        }
    }
});
```

I am getting below error on IE 9 and 10

```
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'getElementsByTagName' 
jquery.min.js, line 16 character 59008
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'top' of undefined or null reference 
base.js, line 48 character 9
```

Comment: The error implies the selector `#footerCenter` is incorrect and returns no visible elements. Can you post the HTML to go with this? (or better yet a JSFiddle)

Comment: What do you expect `this` to be in the code: `$(window).bind('scroll', ... $(this).attr('scrollY')` ?

Comment: @HiTechMagic: above code works in chrome.

Comment: @Sergio : I am trying to move the content of page on mouse scroll.

Comment: jsfiddle anything that is this specific

Comment: This could be a bug with the specific version of JQuery. One of the replies to a similar issue recomends upgrading to 1.7.2 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10923239/javascript-errors-on-internet-explorer-with-jquery-but-working-fine-on-firefox

Answer (score 0):

im pretty sure

```
$(this).attr('scrollY')
```

should be

```
this.scrollY
```

to my knowledge it's nto a valid attribute